# Function using dateadd to return status pl sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a table named `Borrowing` with columns `id`, `borrow_date` and `duration`. I want to create a function to check the status. If someone wants to borrow the book, they give 2 parameters (`v_book` and `v_date`). `v_book` is the book id they want to borrow and `v_date` is the date they want to borrow. This function checks whether the book can be borrowed or not.
Example, user input `v_book=100`, and `v_date='5-Jan-2020'`. But in the table, the book with id 100, the borrow_date is '4-Jan-2020' and the duration is 3 days. So January 4th plus 3 days is January 7th. So that means the book cannot be borrowed by January 5th.
This is my code so far and I still got an error in the `dateadd`. I need to write the function using Oracle PL/SQL. Any idea? Thanks!

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_status (v_book INT, v_date DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2;
v_duration INT;
v_borrow date;
BEGIN
SELECT duration INTO v_duration FROM Borrowing WHERE id = v_book;
SELECT borrow_date INTO v_borrow FROM Borrowing WHERE id = v_book;
SELECT DATEADD(day, v_duration, v_borrow) AS DateAdd;
IF(v_date<DateAdd) THEN
RETURN 'False';
ELSE RETURN 'True';
END IF;
END;
/
DECLARE
m_book INT:=205;
m_date DATE:='5-JAN-2020';
BEGIN
if(check_status(m_book,m_date)='True') then
dbms_output.put_line('You may borrow the book');
else then dbms_output.put_line('book not available');
END;
/
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Where in [the Oracle manual](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/index.html) did you find `dateadd()`?

Comment: Unrelated, but: the first two SELECT statements can be combined into one

Answer (score 1):

`dateadd` isn't an Oracle function.

If you want to add days to a date in Oracle, you simply add the number of days to the date.

E.g. 2 days from now would be `sysdate + 2`.

N.B. if you are assigning a date to a DATE variable, please explicitly convert strings into dates first, e.g.

```
m_date DATE := to_date('05/01/2020', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

By forcing a string into a DATE variable, you're forcing an implicit conversion, which uses the NLS_DATE_FORMAT parameter of your session as the format of your string, e.g. Oracle will do the following behind the scenes:

```
m_date DATE := to_date('5-JAN-2020', <NLS_DATE_FORMAT>);
```

If your NLS_DATE_FORMAT doesn't match the string you've passed in, you'll get an error. By explicitly converting, you've made your code able to run on any session, regardless of the NLS_DATE_FORMAT setting.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your function code as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_status (v_book INT, v_date DATE) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS -- this was missing in your code
v_cnt number:= 0;
BEGIN
SELECT count(1)
INTO v_cnt
 FROM Borrowing
WHERE id = v_book
AND v_date between borrow_date and borrow_date + duration ;

IF(cnt > 0) THEN
RETURN 'False';
ELSE RETURN 'True';
END IF;
END;
/
```

Also, you can call this function using the `SELECT` query as follows:

```
Select check_status(205, date'2020-01-05')
From dual;
```

Please note how dates are created in oracle.

Comment: This doesn't work if `v_date` is `2020-01-10` and there is a reservation for the book starting from `2020-02-01` as you never check the lower bound of the reservation, only the upper bound.

Comment: Lower bound can not be checked as there is no duration available with function as an input for checking status.

Comment: Of course you can check it, you check if `v_date` is between `borrow_date` and `borrow_date + duration`. There does not need to be an input duration if the OP is asking about a particular time instant; they may want to extend their function to include that but it is not what the question is asking.

Comment: And what if status check is for starting with v_date to lets sqy 100 daya(duration). I think function itself should have duration as an input parameter else it will be logically incorrect and produces bugs.. but yes, I have updated answer according to your suggestion. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the many syntax errors, your function will not work as a book can be borrowed many times and you need to check all the times that it has been borrowed to make sure none of them overlap with the instant you want to start borrowing.

You want to check something like this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_status (
  v_book BORROWING.ID%TYPE,
  v_date DATE
) RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  v_is_borrowed NUMBER(1,0);
BEGIN
  SELECT COUNT(*)
  INTO   v_is_borrowed
  FROM   Borrowing
  WHERE  id = v_book
  AND    borrow_date <= v_date
  AND    borrow_date + duration > v_date;

  RETURN CASE v_is_borrowed WHEN 0 THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE borrowing( id, borrow_date, duration ) AS
SELECT 205, DATE '2020-01-01', 31 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 205, DATE '2020-02-10', 10 FROM DUAL;
```

Then:

```sql
BEGIN
  IF check_status( 205, DATE '2020-01-05' ) = 'True' THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('You may borrow the book');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('book not available');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> `book not available`

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=1724ece06860132012cd0cba1707f9ab)*

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the database table.

```sql
create table BORROWING (ID number(3), BORROW_DATE date, DURATION number(2));
```

2. Insert a sample row.

```sql
insert into BORROWING values (100, to_date('04-01-2021','DD-MM-YYYY'), 3);
```

3. Create the function. (I changed the names and types slightly.)

```sql
create or replace function CHECK_STATUS(P_BOOK BORROWING.ID%type,
                                        P_DATE BORROWING.BORROW_DATE%type)
return boolean
is
  L_DUMMY number(1);
begin
  select 1
    into L_DUMMY
    from BORROWING
   where ID = P_BOOK
     and P_DATE between BORROW_DATE and (BORROW_DATE + DURATION);
  return false;
exception
  when NO_DATA_FOUND then
    return true;
end;
/
```

If the desired borrow date for the desired book falls within a period where the book is already borrowed, then the function returns *false*.

4. Test the function. (Again changed the names and types.)

```sql
declare
  L_BOOK BORROWING.ID%type;
  L_DATE BORROWING.BORROW_DATE%type;
begin
  L_BOOK := 100;
  L_DATE := to_date('05-01-2021','DD-MM-YYYY');
  if CHECK_STATUS(L_BOOK, L_DATE) then
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('You may borrow the book.');
  else
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Book not available.');
  end if;
end;
/
```

Of-course the function only checks that the book is available on the intended borrow date. The function does not check whether the book can be borrowed for the intended duration. For that, you would need to check the intended duration also.

Refer to this [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=8a6e9faa1b9f9275abc70f961861e3e6)

Answer (score 0):

You can put all statements into one SELECT Statement during the creation of the function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION check_status(
                                        i_book Borrowing.Id%type, 
                                        i_date Borrowing.Borrow_Date%type
                                       )
  RETURN VARCHAR2 IS
    o_borrowed VARCHAR2(5);
BEGIN
  SELECT DECODE(SIGN(COUNT(*)),0,'True','False')
    INTO v_borrowed
    FROM Borrowing
   WHERE id = i_book
     AND i_date BETWEEN borrow_date AND borrow_date + duration - 1;
   
  RETURN o_borrowed;   
END;
/
```

and then revoke such as

```
DECLARE
  v_book     Borrowing.Id%type := 205;
  v_date     Borrowing.Borrow_Date%type := date'2020-01-05';
BEGIN
  IF check_status(v_book, v_date) = 'True' THEN
    dbms_output.put_line('You may borrow the book');
  ELSE
    dbms_output.put_line('book not available');
  END IF;
END;
/
```

where there's no predefined function called `DATEADD()` in Oracle database.

Alternatively, you can create a PROCEDURE as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE check_status(
                                         i_book     Borrowing.Id%type, 
                                         i_date     Borrowing.Borrow_Date%type,
                                         o_borrowed OUT VARCHAR2
                                        ) IS
BEGIN
  SELECT DECODE(SIGN(COUNT(*)),0,'You may borrow the book','book not available')
    INTO o_borrowed
    FROM Borrowing
   WHERE id = i_book
     AND i_date BETWEEN borrow_date AND borrow_date + duration - 1;   
END;
/
```

and print the description which you want out directly as

```
DECLARE
  v_book     Borrowing.Id%type := 205;
  v_date     Borrowing.Borrow_Date%type := date'2020-01-05';
  v_borrowed VARCHAR2(50);
BEGIN
  check_status(v_book, v_date,v_borrowed);
  dbms_output.put_line(v_borrowed);
END;
/
```